# Create a Trigger to change values before insert in Informix

Tags: sql, informix, spl

We have a table with a date field.  Also there are some old apps we can't modify whose inserts that date field  with string ("yyyy-mm-dd") (Yeah, SQL Injectión Party!!). Now it's needed to change that field to a Datetime year to second. This makes that old apps fail.

```
create table test(
    testDate DATETIME YEAR TO SECOND
);

insert into  test values("2018-12-12")

Error: A field in a datetime or interval value is incorrect or an illegal operation specified on datetime field.
```

We are trying to make a trigger to concatenate  " 00:00:00" to the string if its length is 10. That should correct the problem.

It's that even posible?
Seems to me that if I use a before insert trigger, I can't modify the insert values. But if I use for each row instead, the trigger is not launched because the Error is throwed first.

Any Idea?

Comment: Maybe create a VIEW for the old apps and use an INSTEAD trigger? The "date" column in the VIEW may be a DATE type or maybe even a VARCHAR and then use the INSTEAD trigger to convert the value to a DATETIME.

Comment: I think you'll have to do as @Luis suggests: rename the base table, create a view with the original name and INSTEAD OF triggers on it so that when the old applications insert into the view, the INSTEAD OF actions can make the changes necessary.